# Convert QDate to seconds

Tags: pyqt4, python-2.6, date-conversion, seconds, qdatetime

I take date from `QDateTimeEdit` and convert it to seconds like this:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

date = self.__ui.dateTimeEdit.date().toString("dd/MM/yy")
dateString = str(date)

seconds = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(dateString, "%d/%m/%y").timetuple())
```

This works well, but since it looks to long to me, my question is: Is it possible to convert `self.__ui.dateTimeEdit.date()` directly, without those string conversions?

**EDIT1**
Unfortunately `toMSecsSinceEpoch()` as falsetru suggested, doesn't work for me.

```
AttributeError: 'QDateTime' object has no attribute 'toMSecsSinceEpoch'
```

I'm using PyQt 4.7.1 for Python 2.6

**EDIT2** based on jonrsharpe's answer I've escaped string conversions:

```
    date = self.__ui.dateTimeEdit.date().toPyDate()
    seconds = time.mktime(date.timetuple())
```

result is the same.

**EDIT3** even shorter solution based on falsetru's comment:

```
self.__ui.dateTimeEdit.dateTime().toTime_t()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`QDateTime.toMSecsSinceEpoch`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdatetime.html#toMSecsSinceEpoch):

```
>>> import PyQt4.QtCore
>>> d = PyQt4.QtCore.QDateTime(2014, 2, 20, 17, 10, 30)
>>> d.toMSecsSinceEpoch() / 1000
1392883830L
```

**UPDATE**

Alternative using [`QDateTime.toTime_t`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdatetime.html#toTime_t):

```
>>> d = PyQt4.QtCore.QDateTime(2014, 2, 20, 17, 10, 30)
>>> d.toTime_t()
1392883830L
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'QDateTime' object has no attribute 'toMSecsSinceEpoch'` . I'm using Python 2.6, PyQt4, is that a problem?

Comment: @Aleksandar, It works for me. I'm using Python 2.7.6 + PyQt4 4.10.2.

Comment: @Aleksandar, According to [Qt QDateTime Class documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toMSecsSinceEpoch), the method is introduced in Qt 4.7. Check you Qt/PyQt version.

Comment: @Aleksandar, Did you try jonrsharpe's answer? If that does not work, try `toPyDateTime`.

Comment: @Aleksandar, Did you try `self.__ui.dateTimeEdit.toTime_t()` ?

Comment: `'QDateTimeEdit' object has no attribute 'toTime_t'` It's maybe because of python 2.6

Comment: @Aleksandar, Ah, missed `dateTime()`: `self.__ui.dateTimeEdit.dateTime().toTime_t()`

Answer (score 1):

The `QDate` you get from

```
self.__ui.dateTimeEdit.date()
```

has another method [`toPyDate`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdate.html#toPyDate) that will save you the round trip through a string.