# How to convert date into seconds. (Python) (PyQt4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have a `QDateTime` which stores the time and the date in a fromat like this

```
>>> now = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
>>> print(now)
>>> PyQt4.QtCore.QDateTime(2015, 8, 28, 17, 15, 33, 340)
```

And I have `QDateTimeEdit` which stores the date in the same format as above.

What I'm trying to do is convert **the difference** between the two DateTimes in seconds.

So 28.8.2015 17:20 (DD.M.YYYY HH:SS) and 28.8.2015 17:25 would be difference 5 minutes and that's 300 (seconds).

Is there a simple and pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901736/convert-qdate-to-seconds)? Does it help you?

Comment: Too bad I can't select a comment as an anwser. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: It's fine. Your question doesn't need an accepted answer in this case. It should be marked as a duplicate of the linked one.

Answer (score 0):

use the **secsTo** function

```
now = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
#got the current time 
dt2 = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString("1-1-98 00:01:02","M-d-yy hh:mm:ss")
#got another date
t = now.secsTo (dt2)
#t is the difference between these two times in seconds
tms =now.msecsTo (dt2)
#tms is the difference between these two times in milliseconds
```

another way is to get the time stamps of both dates and find the difference between the time stamps

```
now = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
#got the current time 
dt2 = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString("1-1-98 00:01:02","M-d-yy hh:mm:ss")
#got another date

t = now.toTime_t()- dt2.toTime_t()
#t is the difference between these two times in seconds
```